# When using Autofac's autoregister functionality, how can I specify that one type should be InstancePerRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

We have a Web API project and using the Autofac Web API Integration as the IoC container. The code that we use to register all of our types is as follows:

```
public class CompositionRootConfigurator
{
    public static AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver Configure(Assembly servicesAssembly)
    {
        var container = BuildContainer(servicesAssembly);
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        return resolver;
    }

    public static IContainer BuildContainer(Assembly servicesAssembly)
    {
        /*TO DELETE ONCE THE REFERENCES ISSUE IS RESOLVED!*/
        var dummy = new EmployeesBL(new ContextFactory(new DBContextFactory(new RoleBasedSecurity(), new Identity())));

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        if (servicesAssembly != null) // this is a temporary workaround, we need a more solid approach here
        {
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(servicesAssembly);
        }

        /* Registers all interfaces and their implementations from the following assemblies in the IoC container
         * 1. CB.CRISP.BL
         * 2. CB.CRISP.BL.CONTRACTS
         * 3. CB.CRISP.DAL
         * 4. CB.CRISP.DAL.CONTRACTS
         * The current assembly is excluded because the controllers were registered with the builder.RegisterApiControllers expression above.
        */
        var appAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .Where(a => a.ToString().StartsWith("CB.CRISP"))
            .ToArray();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(appAssemblies).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        if (servicesAssembly != null)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(servicesAssembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Now suppose we have a **MyType** which implements **IMyType** and this is the only one that must be a single instance per request and it will be injected in several objects along the hierarchy.

I am at a loss in how to specify this within this existing code. If I just go ahead and just do

```
builder.RegisterType<MyType>()
       .As<IMyType>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

since it will also be registered with all the others Will one registration overwrite the other one, will they be duplicated, are there potential problems?

Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Autofac will override the first registration and will accept the last one. [Here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations.) is more detail.

So you should register `MyType` after registering all type.

I haven't seen any potential problem of this.

But you can register all types like this to be sure.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(servicesAssembly).Except<MyType>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

[Here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html) is more detail about scanning.